# Surface Controller or Custom Controller in Umbraco 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

### History

I'm a Web Forms developer with some .NET MVC experience, new to Umbraco and learning as I go.

So far I've been following the Umbraco documentation and videos to get set up which means all my controllers inherit from a "Controller Base" with common functions included, which in itself inherits from SurfaceController.

Recently however, I have noticed some bloggers and external reference material referencing RenderMvcController in the base class instead of SurfaceController - now the Umbraco documentation is unclear on the real differences between the two, nor which situations you should use them in.

### The Question

Is there a clear and distinct difference between the imagined usage scenarios for a Surface Controller - inheriting from ***Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController***, and a Custom Controller - inheriting from ***Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController***?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The documentation for the `SurfaceController` is here: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/surface-controllers

In a nutshell, the `SurfaceController` is used for helping to interact with views. So for example you could post a form to a surface controller. Or you could write a child action to a view with a `SurfaceController`

`RenderMvcController` is used purely for routing to published pages. So you could sub-class `RenderMvcController` in order to 'hijack' requests to published pages of a specific Document Type. See here http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/custom-controllers.

Comment: `SurfaceController` is also typically used to expose APIs that make use of Umbraco content.

Comment: Yes it _can_ be but shouldn't be, since there is `UmbracoApiController` for this very purpose. The two main purposes of surface controllers are form interaction and child actions.

Answer (score 7):

To further clarify based on Digbyswift's answer:

[`SurfaceController`](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/surface-controllers) = APIs or form targets (that then redirect)

[`RenderMvcController`](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/custom-controllers) = custom logic to build a model or select a view for a content item (based on Document Type and, optionally, template)

Comment: Although you are right in that it _can_ be used for APIs, I personally wouldn't recommend it. Umbraco provides the `UmbracoApiController` specifically for this purpose. This method has less overhead than using the SurfaceController. Also, Using surface controllers lumps all your API code in with MVC-specific form handling and child action code which I personally think isn't great. Separate routing can also then be defined for the API too.

Comment: Good call @Digbyswift!